# Enabling/Disabling button with Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, salesforce, visualforce

**Problem :**
I have an apex:commandButton on a VisualForce page, and a js file with some logic in it. Currently, this logic affects whether the button is visible or invisible on the page, using css. I need to change this so it makes the button enabled or disabled. However, whenever I try to disable the button in the js file, the onscreen button doesn't get affected. I am not experienced with front-end dev so may be missing or misunderstanding something obvious.

**Button on .page file :**

```
    <apex:commandButton id="commitButton"
        action="{!commitSelectedLines}"
        value="{!$Label.commitSelectedLines}"/>
```

**.js file (heavily edited down to the seemingly relevant bits) :**

```
FFDCBalancer = (function(){

    /**
     * Singleton Balancer object to maintain balances on the page.
     */
    var balancer = {

        /** JQuery button component for the commit button. */
        cmdCommit: undefined,

        /** Set the enabled-ness of the commit button. */
        setCommitEnabled : function(value) {
            //I PRESUMABLY NEED TO CHANGE THIS BIT TO USE 'DISABLED'.
            this.cmdCommit.css({
               'display': value ? 'block' : 'none'
            });

            //I HAVE TRIED VARIOUS BITS OF CODE, SUCH AS THIS
            //this.cmdCommit.disabled = value;

        },

        /**
         * Respond to refresh by connecting event handlers and calculating the balances.
         */
        onRefresh : function () {
            var me = this;
            me.cmdCommit = $FFDC('#commitButton');
        }
    };

    $FFDC(document).on('FFDCRefresh', function(){ balancer.onRefresh(); });
    return balancer;
}());
```

Comment: You might need to include the actual HTML output in your post  as well. This looks like serverside code:

<apex:commandButton id="commitButton"
        action="{!commitSelectedLines}"
        value="{!$Label.commitSelectedLines}"/>

Comment: I used Chrome to get the html page. Its massive, but I did find this - <input id="p1:f1:pb1:j_id10:commitButton" type="submit" name="p1:f1:pb1:j_id10:commitButton" value="Commit Selected Lines" class="btn">

Comment: How does this function work? `$FFDC('#commitButton')`.  If it is using sizzle like jQuery, then remember that VF will prepend additional ids to the one you set, that is `commitButton` will not be your final Id.  One way to retrieve VF components with jQuery is to use the raw Id attribute along with the ends with shortcut.  Like `$FFDC(':submit[id$=":commitButton"]')`.  This will find all input types of submit where the id ends with ":commitButton".

Comment: Otherwise, if it is returning the element correctly, then you can disable it with `.prop('disabled', true)`

Comment: Thanks Scott. I've tried $FFDC(':submit[id$=":commitButton"]').prop('disabled', true); but to no avail. Is that what you meant?

Comment: In ASP.NET, you can retrieve the Control.ClientID, which will return the generated id. Probably, there will be such a thing in VisualForce as well? (refer to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientid(v=vs.110).aspx for more info on ASP.NET ClientID)

Answer (score 0):

For this, you can do one of two things:

1. Use the {!$Component...commitButton} to get the client-side ID, though it can really mess JQuery up, since it adds a colon between the IDs, so you'll have to use it in combination with document.getElementById(...)   - For example:

   `jQuery(document.getElementById('{!$Component.Form.commitButton}')).attr('disabled','disabled');`
2. Put a "styleClass" on the button, and change it using that:

   `<apex:commandButton id="commitButton"
       action="{!commitSelectedLines}"
       value="{!$Label.commitSelectedLines}" styleClass="commitButtonClass" />`

Then use jQuery to set the attribute:

`jQuery(".commitButtonClass").attr('disabled','disabled');`